# try...catch with addEventListener

Tags: javascript, try-catch, addeventlistener

The try...catch block is not capturing this error when it comes from an event listener registered on `window`. It's the same behaviour in Firefox, Chrome and Safari.
I realise that I could wrap the contents of the function but why doesn't it work in this form? I was hoping to wrap a large amount of code in this way and track errors silently.

```
try{

    function onLoad(){
        var a = b;
    }

    //onLoad(); //This is caught
    window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false); //This is not caught

}
catch(e){
    console.log("Catch: ", e);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This happened because this code:

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false); //This is not caught
```

run after the page has loaded. This code is executing after try catch block.
To get the required behavior you must use window.onerror.

Comment: Is there any way to see the reason why it failed?

Answer (score 0):

Because of the code

```
window.addEventListener('load', onLoad, false)
```

Just call to attach the function onLoad to the 'onLoad' event of window, it can not rise any error,
The error come from function onLoad itself, you should do the try catch inside that function